# WCF Not Timing out correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, timeout

I am having a timeout issue, these are the details:

My binding configuration looks like this:

```
<netTcpBinding>
 <binding name="WindowsServerOverTcp"
   maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000"
   maxBufferSize="10000000"
   maxBufferPoolSize="10000000"
   closeTimeout="00:00:03"
  openTimeout="00:00:03"
  sendTimeout="00:00:03"
  receiveTimeout="00:00:03">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
  maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
  maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
  <security mode="None">
  </security>
 </binding>
 </netTcpBinding>
```

I am sending a message to a server which I know is turned off so the connection should just time out after 3 seconds as stipulated in my app.config, but for some reason it is taking 20-30 seconds.

When the EndPointNotFoundException is thrown this is the info I get:

> System.ServiceModel.EndPointNotFoundException:
>   Could not connect to
>   net.tcp://10.0.0.82:4466/MegaMatcherWcf.
>   The connection attempt lasted for a
>   time span of 00:00:03. TCP error code
>   10060: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to
>   respond 10.0.0.82:4466

If I try the same test with the machine turned on, but no listening software running I get the expected behaviour, with the connection timing out after 3 seconds. Why if the machine is off does it take 30 seconds, and then tell me it took 3 seconds?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you are dealing with a Windows timeout issue now, not your WCF timeout.  Windows will take 20-30 seconds to determine that a machine is not responding on the network.  When you make your call to the WCF server, Windows first has to establish a route to the server.  When it can't, it alerts your software and your software thinks that it reached its own timeout.  Your system never gets to the point of actually polling to see if the service is running because Windows is still trying to find something at the other end of that IP address.

Comment: Just to clarify, each connection I make is a fresh connection, I am not holding onto an existing connection. I would have thought considering this is a Microsoft technology that they would have overridden the default TCP time out for such cases? What's the point in having a connectTimeout property if it only works when the machines turned on?

Comment: @Adrian - it is frustrating but I believe the reason why this is the case is because WCF is letting the OS establish the base connection (getting the path to the server).  This is letting the OS do what it does best.  Unfortunately, this means we are dependent on the OS timeout when the server is off.

Comment: @ BiggsTRC Thanks for the info, really was confusing me, I'll remember for next time! I am going to have to put all my connections onto a SmartThread pool so that these time-outs don't slow my application down.

Comment: Is there a way to increase the Windows timeouts?

Answer (score 17):

To be a bit more specific than @BiggsTRC (whose answer is broadly correct):

- WCF delegates to the `System.Net.Sockets` classes the details of
  establishing the transport layer connection in
  a NetTcpBinding channel;
- `System.Net.Sockets` is a wrapper around the unmanaged WINSOCK API;
- The WINSOCK API has internal default timeouts but does not provide any documented mechanism for specifying a timeout on certain blocking operations, including `WSAConnect()`, which the .NET `Socket.Connect()` method uses;
- The WCF code (in `System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionInitiator.Connect()`) calls `Socket.Connect`, and if this throws an exception of certain types, it checks to see whether there is any remaining time in its connection timeout period. If there isn't, you get an `EndpointNotFoundException` with the error message you have seen;
- WCF uses a `TimeoutHelper` class to keep track of timeout periods and do the time arithmetic. This has a method called `ElapsedTime`, but this is a misnomer since it never returns a value greater than the original timeout period: that is the reason the error message lies to you about how long the connection attempt took.

WCF could enforce its configured timeouts by using the asynchronous methods of the Sockets API, monitoring the timeout on a separate thread to the connect attempt, but it does not currently do so. If you think this is a bug (which arguably it is) you could report it on [Microsoft's Connect Site](http://connect.microsoft.com/) and perhaps get it fixed in a future version or service pack.

Comment: Thanks for you input Chris, I will probably report this as it seems a bit crazy to provide a timeout parameter which is not the effective connection timeout. You would think considering MS developed WCF, they could easily override the API defaults.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem

Did every thing, tried every configuration nothing helped.

net.tcp over internet is timing out like hell on lengthy processes

the only thing that helped me is when i used

> Duplex or Callback Message Exchange Pattern

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff395349.aspx