# Enforce WCF client SendTimeout

Tags: wcf, timeout

I have strict timeout requirements for my WCF client proxy. At the moment I set all my `basicHttpBinding` timeouts (`Open`, `Close`, `Send`, and `Receive`) to 1 second. However, when there's a connection break between my client and the service, it always takes around 21-22 seconds before the timeoute occurs.

I considered that it might be a slow / failing DNS lookup, but by substituting the hostname in the endpoint URL with an IP address had no effect.

Is this the expected behaviour? Should I manage these timeouts requirements myself with something such as application timers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966315/wcf-not-timing-out-correctly/5989738#5989738) explain why you experience this.

You will need to implement a timeout yourself if it is important to you unless/until Microsoft can be persuaded to change the WCF implementation.

Comment: Thanks! I see my Googling skills were somewhat lacking today.