# sendTimeout exceeded by the client on Timeout Exception

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to reduce the timeout/EndPointNotFound exception time to 10 seconds. Logs of Exception suggest that the call gets timeout in 10 seconds but if i add the code with StopWatch it takes around 21 - 22 seconds.

I have read the same on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966315/wcf-not-timing-out-correctly/5989738#5989738) link.

Is it really a bug ?. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 SendTimeout is used to initialize the OperationTimeout, which governs the whole interaction for sending a message

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/librarysystem.servicemodel.configuration.standardbindingelement.sendtimeout.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms731343.aspx

> It's not a bug

2 you can adjust property sendTimeout="" in binding section

Comment: If i set the sendTimeout to 10 seconds, it does not give me EndPointNotFound/TimeOut exception in 10 seconds, it takes 21-22 seconds.

Comment: you have another problem it's not relative to operation